# Android Documentation - String a primitive type? Confusion

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, primitive, primitive-types

I was reading Android documentation regarding **Shared Preferences** [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) And they have mentioned one thing,

> You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings.

To best of my knowledge there are 8 primitive types in Java ie. `byte, char, short, int, long, float, double, boolean`

String is a **class** in Java under **java.lang** package, not a primitive type.

So questions arise,

Q1. Why this thing is written in Android documentation that Primitive data: string?

Q2. Does this primitive word used here, mean something else than the primitive data type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that strings are [not a primitive data type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) in Java:

> In addition to the eight primitive data types listed above, the Java programming language also provides special support for character strings via the `java.lang.String` **class**.
>
> Enclosing your character string within double quotes will automatically create a new `String` **object**; for example, `String s = "this is a string";`.
>
> The `String` class is not technically a primitive data type, but considering the special support given to it by the language, you'll probably tend to think of it as such.

However, it may be that, in *this* context, "primitive" refers not to the Java primitive types but to a scale from simple to complex.

That page you reference has, in the "storage quick view", the following points:

- Use Shared Preferences for *primitive* data
- Use internal device storage for private data
- Use external storage for *large* data sets that are not private
- Use SQLite databases for *structured* storage

That seems to run the scale from simple to complex (primitive, large and structured).

Or it may be that Android just follows the text mentioned in the Java tutorials (see above) and treats strings as a primitive type, despite the fact it's not technically the case.

You know, the same way we claim Java is object-oriented despite the fact that Python/Ruby/Smalltalk fans will argue that the presence of primitive types makes that claim false, right up until the point until your ears drop off to protect your sanity :-)

In any case, I'm not sure it matters. Android is specified by the *Android* documentation primarily, with Java documentation as fallback (as you can see by their differing approaches to internationalisation). It was meant to leverage the Java skills out there rather than provide the *exact* same environment.

If the Android documentation refers to strings as primitive, it considers them primitive, at least in terms of what you can use for shared preferences.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer. "Primitive" in this context just means "simple" (or maybe "atomic"). You can also store `Set<String>` in `SharedPreferences`, and that's not a primitive type by any stretch of the imagination. :)

Answer (score 1):

String Type object is called String `literals` (means very Close to Primitive ). means you can use String object as same as Primitive datatypes, that means there is no need of creating object by new. You can directly assign any values to string object without saying `new` like:  `Sting str = new String();`.

```
int i = 10;
String str = "abc"; // By the same way of primitive.
```

From http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3

> String allocation, like all object allocation, proves costly in both
>   time and memory. The JVM performs some trickery while instantiating
>   string literals to increase performance and decrease memory overhead.
>   To cut down the number of String objects created in the JVM, the
>   String class keeps a pool of strings. Each time your code create a
>   string literal, the JVM checks the string literal pool first. If the
>   string already exists in the pool, a reference to the pooled instance
>   returns. If the string does not exist in the pool, a new String object
>   instantiates, then is placed in the pool. Java can make this
>   optimization since strings are immutable and can be shared without
>   fear of data corruption.

Comment: Careful, there is such a thing as a `String` _literal_. But _literal_ is not a type as defined in the JLS.

Answer (score 1):

The `String` class is not technically a primitive data type, but considering the special support given to it by the language, you'll probably tend to think of it as such.

for more you can refer this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score -2):

> Why this thing is written in Android documentation that Primitive data: string?

Actually primitive types can be a wrapper classes which can be used to saved data in the `Shared Preferences`. `String` actually wraps the `char[]`

> Does this primitive word used here, mean something else than the primitive data type?

Nope. You can use wrapper classes which can be a primitive type

Comment: ....An instance of a wrapper class *by definition* can't be a primitive. It can represent *the same value* as a primitive, but isn't one. In addition, `char[]` isn't a primitive.

Comment: well,can you please clarify "if we use a wrapper class for a primitive type can we say that wrapper class a primitive type?" @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Even I wanted to ask the same question. Can wrapper classes too be called to be Primitive Types? Primitive types are basic data types we have as I mentioned in Question but can we call Wrapper classes too to be Primitive Types?

Comment: @GPS NO NO NO NO. Primitives are *exactly* the 8 types you already defined. Every thing else is *by definition* a reference type. It's spelled out in the JLS -- if it's not a primitive type, it's a reference type. Instances of wrapper classes can *represent* the same *value* that a primitive type can hold, but they are *not* primitive types. I don't know why this answer is getting upvotes when it's *wrong*.

Comment: @user3580294 char[] is a sequence of primitive types.

Comment: But a `char[]` itself is not a primitive. If `String` is considered a primitive because it wraps a `char[]`, should all other primitive arrays be called primitives too? Because that's wrong.

Comment: @Saif Yes, you can call a wrapper class a primitive type.. this example: int a = new Integer(1);

Comment: @user3580294 Thanks. That is what I do believe. That the variables are the primitive types and wrapper classes are NOT primitive types, they are reference type. I want to clear one more doubt here. Can we call Wrapper classes to be Non-Primitive type then? I am actually confused at this thing.

Comment: @user3580294 I didnt say that char[] is a primitive type but what OP is saying that it can be used by the Shared Preferences and extract all of its primitive type from the array.

Comment: That example is *wrong*. The wrapper class *represents* the same value as the primitive `1`. It is *not* a primitive type. In addition, that is an example of *autoboxing*, where the value represented by the `Integer` is being assigned to the primitive variable `a`. It does *not* mean that `Integer` is a primitive type. If not for the autoboxing mechanism, that code would not compile at all.

Comment: @GPS Yes, instances of wrapper classes are non-primitive, as they are objects. An instance can represent the same value as a given primitive, but that does not make it a primitive.

Comment: You didn't say that `char[]` is a primitive, but it's extremely heavily implied the way you worded it. You said that primitive types can be wrapper classes, after which you say that `String` wraps `char[]`. In short, you imply that `String` is a wrapper type for the primitive type `char[]`. Which is wrong.

Comment: @user3580294 It's good to have you the part of this discussion man. Plz check this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class Why they have written Primitive Wrapper Class? It made me to be worried about my concept of Primitive data types and wrapper classes. I think they should rename it to just Wrapper Classes rather than Primitive Wrapper classes. What you say?

Comment: @GPS It might help to "go backwards" -- going from more general descriptors to more specific ones, which in this case basically means reading from right to left. A primitive wrapper class is a class that wraps primitives, which makes sense, right? Just "wrapper class" is a bit general -- it's possible to wrap other things, like input streams and such.

Comment: @GPS, I think that probably should be read as "primitive-wrapper class" (a class that wraps a primitive), not "primitive wrapper-class", a wrapper class that would be primitive. This is also implied by "...  is one of eight classes provided in the java.lang package to provide object methods for the eight primitive types." in that link.